# How to create users and passwords for Jenkins using JCASC

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jcasc

I am trying to create a user and password for Jenkins using JCASC.  I can set up Jenkins however when I go to the GUI on my local host I do not see any users.  Here is my code

```
jenkins:
  systemMessage: "Jenkins configured automatically by Jenkins Configuration as Code plugin\n\n"
  disabledAdministrativeMonitors:
      - "jenkins.diagnostics.ControllerExecutorsNoAgents"
credentials:
  system:
    domainCredentials:
    - credentials:
      - usernamePassword:
          id: "admin-cred"
          username: "jenkins-admin"
          password: "butler"
          scope: GLOBAL
```

I believe I have all the necessary plugins installed but something is missing clearly.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What you have done here is defined a credential for using an SCM, like git. `securityRealm` is used for Jenkins server's users

Answer (score 2):

The way I got users to pop up is by setting up the (local) security realm, rather than credentials, like so:

```
jenkins:
  securityRealm:
    local:
      users:
       - id: jenkins-admin
         password: butler
```

I'm finding this a great resource to get ideas from: https://github.com/oleg-nenashev/demo-jenkins-config-as-code

Comment: I tried that for another user. a.k.a, I have already admin defined, and then I tried to add another user, but jenkins doesn't create the second user. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've used a local security Realm with disabled signups to add the user "jenkins-admin".

```
jenkins:
    . . .
    securityRealm:
        local:
            allowsSignup: false
            users: 
                - id: jenkins-admin
                  password: butler
```

You can refer below links to know more about Jcasc:

- https://www.jenkins.io/projects/jcasc/
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin

Comment: I tried that for another user. a.k.a, I have already admin defined, and then I tried to add another user, but jenkins doesn't create the second user. any thoughts?